# have call post api into get data and then print but my var userdata = [user]() recived data empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, urlsession

```
    func fetchMovies(completion: @escaping(Data) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos") else { return }
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching movies: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
            guard let jsonData = data else { return }
            //print(jsonD)
            completion(jsonData)
            
        }
        
        dataTask.resume()
    }

}
```

This is my main UIViewController class I have receive in api response data but my caret "var userdata = user" in this receive data empty not insert in data how is it possible to this problem solving

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var userdata = [user]()
    {
        didSet{
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        tableView.dataSource = self
//        tableView.delegate = self

        print(userdata)
        let movieManager = MovieManager()
        
        movieManager.fetchMovies { data in
           // print(data)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do{
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode([user].self, from: data)
                self.userdata = decodedData
               // print(decodedData)
                
            }catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //print(userdata.count)
        return userdata.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = userdata[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: You get **post**data but you are going to display **user**data. By the way please name structs with starting uppercase letter. And never print meaningless literals like `"error"`. Print the `error` instance.

Comment: share the code for user class or struct maybe you have and issue with the decoding